# Dynamics AX 2009: Add a field to InventJournalTrans, propagate to InventTrans

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to add an additional field to **InventJournalTrans**, that after posting will show up in the **InventTrans** table.  The field is a reference column to a record in another table.  What method(s) do I need to modify to make this behavior happen?

Currently, I have already added the fields to both tables and modified the Form to allow the user to enter and save the new field.  I just can't seem to find the bottom of the rabbit hole on where the **actual** posting to **InventTrans** is occurring.

Ideally, it should just be a:

`inventTrans.ReasonRefRecId = inventJournalTrans.ReasonRefRecId;`

assignment statement before the

`inventTrans.insert();`

call. Anybody have a clue on where this is at?

Comment: It looks like a potential solution is listed on the [Microsoft Dynamics Forums](https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/t/53346.aspx) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link above does contain the solution -- I have included the code from that page in case that page disappears or no longer becomes available.  Thanks to gl00mie for answering on that site and providing this answer.

You should create a new InventMovement method like this:

```
public MyNewFieldType myNewField()
{
    return MyNewFieldType::DefaultValue; // suppose your new field is an enum
}
```

Then modify \Classes\InventMovement\initInventTransFromBuffer

```
void initInventTransFromBuffer(InventTrans _inventTrans, InventMovement _movement_orig)
{
    // ... append this line to the end of whatever else is already in this method
    _inventTrans.MyNewField            = this.myNewField();
}
```

And finally overload the new method in the InventMov_Journal class:

```
public MyNewFieldType myNewField()
{
    return inventJournalTrans.MyNewField;
}
```